# JBoss classloading IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, jar, jboss, classloading

I'm migrating a project from JBoss 5 to 6.4.  In the process I've updated several jar files in my build.  I had several ClassCastExceptions which I resolved by taking the version of the specific classes from a jar in the JBoss system modules and using that in my app build.  I've done so with two jars, `jbossweb-7.5.26.Final-redhat-1.jar` and `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar` which contain the classes `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` and `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` respectively.  I'm using both of those jars as libs in my app build and all is compiling without error or warning.  I've confirmed that when I remove those libs the app fails to compile as it can't find the included refernced classes, so I know I'm not actually referencing some other copy of those classes in my build.  The app is deploying fine, but when I try hitting it I get an exception

> JBWEB001018: An exception or error occurred in the container during
>   the request processing: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request does not implement the requested
>   interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

When I look at the class definitions from the jars in my editor (JDeveloper 12c) I can see that `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` as defined in `jbossweb-7.5.26.Final-redhat-1` does in fact implement `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` as defined in `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar`.

I turned on verbose logging of classloading (JAVA_OPT -verbose:class), and confirmed that as JBoss is loading those two classes they are in fact being loaded from those two jar files, not some other one I didn't know about.  I can see in my developer tool that the .class files I'm including in my project are from those same two jar files.

Possibly relevant, the classloading logs say JBoss is loading `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` from `RedHat/JBoss/EAP-6.4.0/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-6.4.18.CP/org/jboss/as/web/main/`. I'm not sure why it's using that copy/location rather than `RedHat\JBoss\EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\web\main`.

So what gives?  What I read on the error would suggest to me that `jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar` was compiled against a different version of HttpServletRequest than `jbossweb-7.5.26.Final-redhat-1` includes.

Is that interpretation or the error correct? Does JBoss 6.4 really ship with incompatible jar files in its system modules?  If so what versions of these jars do I need and how to I check compatibility?  And can I safely switch to a different jar file without introducing more incompatibilities with other jars?  What other causes might I be missing?  Any help much appreciated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that I was not using the modules.xml correctly.  I needed to add dependencies for the two packages in my module.xml file

```
   <dependencies>
      <module name="org.jboss.as.web"/>
      <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
   </dependencies>
```

I had previously added those modules to my war file's jboss-deployment-structure.xml and that did not do the trick and left me with ClassNotFoundExceptions.  My Jboss-deployment-structure.xml now just references my own custom module as a dependency, which in turn has dependencies of its own.

I still don't understand what was causing the previous error, as it's all the same versions of the jar files in question so I don't know where a conflict was, but this got the error to go away and no more ClassNotFoundExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

1/ You shouldn't depend on servlet API implementation
2/ You shouldn't include those implementation classes in your application are they are provided by the server itself
3/ You shouldn't put API jars or their implementation in your application or if you do this you need to exclude those modules from your application using a jboss-deployment.xml

Comment: Thanks much for the reply, but I'm not entirely clear on your comments.
1) what implementation should I depend on?  I need some definition of what the interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest is for my application to compile right?
2) I'm not including those jars in the war file deployment if that's what you are suggesting.
3) I'm not sure the difference between this comment and #2

Comment: org.apache.catalina.connector.Request is not in the API jar but in jbossweb-7.5.26.Final-redhat-1.jar You don't need this file for compiling nor for running. The implementation of the Servlet API is provided by the Java EE server.